# I want an cupertino styled Listtile/Card or something i can use in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i am writing a flutter app and doing a calendar view app. On the front page should be displayed all calendar items. With the date, title, place, and time. The problem is i cant find a good listtile or card for this in cupertino style. I tried the normal card with listtile or only listtile but i wasnt able to generate a good looking cupertino style widget. Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Comment: Please share your code so we can understand what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Please share image or drawing of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thats the problem i tried so many things, and i need some inspirations if some already made something like this

Comment: Highly customizable, feature-packed calendar works like google calendar but with more features: https://flutterawesome.com/highly-customizable-feature-packed-calendar-works-like-google-calendar-but-with-more-features/ @PhilNue

Answer (score 0):

Material Design 3 introduced new types of cards. These can be produced by configuring the Card widget's properties.

To create a local project with this code sample, run:
flutter create --sample=material.Card.3 mysample

After that you can put your calendar over the new style card.

[Info and code was copied from](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const CardExamplesApp());
}

class CardExamplesApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardExamplesApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xff6750a4), useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Card Examples')),
        body: Column(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Spacer(),
            ElevatedCardExample(),
            FilledCardExample(),
            OutlinedCardExample(),
            Spacer(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// An example of the elevated card type.
///
/// The default settings for [Card] will provide an elevated
/// card matching the spec:
///
/// https://m3.material.io/components/cards/specs#a012d40d-7a5c-4b07-8740-491dec79d58b
class ElevatedCardExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ElevatedCardExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Card(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Elevated Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// An example of the filled card type.
///
/// To make a [Card] match the filled type, the default elevation and color
/// need to be changed to the values from the spec:
///
/// https://m3.material.io/components/cards/specs#0f55bf62-edf2-4619-b00d-b9ed462f2c5a
class FilledCardExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const FilledCardExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
        child: const SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Filled Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// An example of the outlined card type.
///
/// To make a [Card] match the outlined type, the default elevation and shape
/// need to be changed to the values from the spec:
///
/// https://m3.material.io/components/cards/specs#0f55bf62-edf2-4619-b00d-b9ed462f2c5a
class OutlinedCardExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const OutlinedCardExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
        ),
        child: const SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Outlined Card')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```